# What to compare this integral with to prove its convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following integral:

$$
\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{x  \ln^2 x} \mathrm{d}x
$$

What should I compare it with in order to prove its convergence? I know how to calculate the integral and find a value, but I want a way that just studies its nature instead of actually calculating it.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want as an answer: Is it a way to prove the convergence of the integral without calculating it explicitly?

Comment: I should compare it to another integral that is convergent and find that mine is smaller than that integral and therefore converges as well. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx

Comment: Compare it to $$\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^{3/2}}. \;;)$$

Comment: You can't compare it with $$\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\alpha}$$for $\alpha>1$, I mean the comparison isn't useful.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Yes that's what I tried first and reached the same conclusion.

Comment: @DanielFischer But why can I tell that one is convergent?

Comment: @user996056 You substitute $t = \ln x$ to get the integral $$\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^{3/2}},$$ which you know converges. It was a tongue-in-cheek comment, since the simplest method for the integral is to directly substitute to get an integral of which you know that it converges.

Comment: If you looks at the behavior of the function as $x \to \infty$ you can see that it tends to $0$. You can also prove that the derivative $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{1}{x \ln ^2 x}$$ is always negative for $x > e$. This would prove that it is a finite area and that it converges. You may want to add a little more rigor however you get the idea. This may be easier than just comparing it to another integral butbi don't know if you have to. In which case I have nothing to say on the matter.